# Визуальное отображение выбранного input типа radio

Tags: jquery, input

Есть список с блоками `div`. В этих блоках есть радио кнопки, которые отвечают за выбор блока. Я хочу сделать выбор определенного `radio` программно, тобишь поставить атрибут `checked`.
Делаю это так: 
`$('div#1').find('input[type=radio][name=offers]').attr('checked', true)`. В самом элементе(html) атрибут появился, но визуально не показывается что он был выбран. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: добавь рабочий пример кода: js,css,html в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь `prop`:

```
$('div#1').find('input[type=radio][name=offers]').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('div#1').find('input[type=radio][name=offers]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: что делает данный код, и как он относится к заданному вопросу?

Comment: ставь это $('div#1').find('input[type=radio][name=offers]').attr('checked', 'checked'); в место $('div#1').find('input[type=radio][name=offers]').attr('checked', true)

Comment: Комментарии - это не место для кода, добавь все что нужно в ответ, и не забудь добавить описание того, что именно делает твой кусок кода